# Can you tweak my Array Formula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

Im taking info from COLUMN C depending on what it contains and giving it a Letter value of say A and so on. Its Working, but it is putting my A in the COLUMN next to where I placed the code for some reason for 'Name2'.

So this code is being placed in COLUMN P. Anything containing Name1 shows an A in COLUMN P but anything Name2 shows an A in Column Q. How can I fix this so everything is in COLUMN P.

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(A3:A),IF(C3:C={"Name1","Name2"},"A","")))
```

Can someone please be kind enough to show me whats wrong? ;  ) Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A value is being populated in the next column because you are effectively creating a 2-column array with the first argument of the IF.

For an array formula you can use the + operator to apply OR logic:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A3:A),IF((C3:C="Name1")+(C3:C="Name2"),"A",""),))`

or if you had a longer list of allowable entries, something like this would be easier to scale:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A3:A),IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(C3:C,{"Name1";"Name2"},0)),"A",""),))`

Comment: I'm using the =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A3:A) to check if there is info in COLUMN A but when there is not, if echoes FLASE, could you advise? BTW Thank you TONS as always!

Comment: If you add that comma near the end of the formula as in this answer, that should take care of it.